# Java programming, String to String conversion error during compilation. Taking input from user and storing it

Tags: java

I am making a program to a get a case input from the user and then store that case entry. However, I am getting an error during compilation,

> demo576.java:44: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted
>   to String [] h=z.Batman();
>             ^ 1 error

the code is as follows:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class demo576
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
fun z=new fun();
String x=z.Batman();
System.out.println(x);

int p=s.nextInt();



String h[]=new String[3];

int i;
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
h=z.Batman();
}

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
System.out.println(h);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Solved. Sorry! My bad! Forgot to do h[i]=z.Batman(); !

Comment: In that case, just delete the question as it has no use for others.

Comment: yes! Thanks! I had it figured! Facepalmed on that silly mistake of mine! Thank you all! And apologies! Forgot to delete it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should suffice:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    h[i] = z.Batman();
}
```

Your print loop needs fixing:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    System.out.println(h[i]);
}
```

P.S. Here is my motto for helping StackOverflow users:

```
System.out.println("He is not a hero. He is a silent guardian, a watchful protector; A DARK KNIGHT!");
```

Comment: yes! Thanks! I had it figured! Facepalmed on that silly mistake of mine! Thank you all! And apologies! Forgot to delete it!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set an array equal to a string. Try this instead (first for loop)

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  h[i] = z.Batman();
```

Good luck!